# Silverlight canvas does not resize on maximize button press

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

In my Silverlight project, I have a couple canvases that all use ScaleTransforms to resize as the browser window size changes. However, if I make my browser window very small, then click the maximize button in the browser, the app stays the same size. How can I make it resize properly when the maximize button is clicked?

The canvas resizes up and down properly when I am resizing the window using the edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the delegate for a resize event was being called after the resize happens (which makes sense); but that I had some conditionals that would prohibit it from resizing if it was already 800x600. If you resized the window quickly, it would not resize properly since it thought it was 800x600; but had in fact shrunk.

**tl;dr** - I did not code my resize event handler correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping your canvas with a [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)?

Comment: Can you post some of your XAML to take a look?

Comment: It was not in the XAML; it was in my event handler. Thanks for your help though!